# How do I automatically pull in references in Visual Studio c# like in Eclipse (java)

Tags: c#

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio so that the intellisence will automatically inset "using" statements (reference to class library) just like in Eclipse (Java)?

This feature is really useful since visual studio only informs you a reference is missing but no suggestions are shown?

Am new to visual studio. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: May I recommend [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)? If you type the name of an unreferenced class, it will prompt you to press `Ctrl` + `Return` which will add the using statement

Answer (score 7):

with the caret over the Type declaration you just typed, press CTRL + ALT + F10 a context menu appears offering to add the using statement. Also apparently (see JohnD's answer) CTRL + . works too and I just tried it, cool, we learn something new every day!

EDIT

oops! sorry that should be: SHIFT + ALT + F10

[image]

Of course that relies on having the relevant dll assembly referenced in the project

[image]

Comment: I think you have installed an extension because I don't have the choices. I have just the two last choices: `generate class...` and `generate new type`.

Comment: @hamed that means you don't have the right reference added to your project

Comment: @hamed see my edits, you need to have the dll referenced, for all the namespaces to be available. See my second screenshot.

Comment: Cool, I did the screenshots cos you said you were new to Visual Studio. I remember being new to Eclipse myself and pictures speek a thousand words :)

Answer (score 6):

If you select the expression that's not resolved, and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (control-period) it will pop up a context menu to add the using statement.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+. will go some of the way to reproduce the functionality. The other alternative is through extension applications, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Importing_Namespaces) is very good for this, and can add references to your project for you too.

Answer (score 0):

There is some extensions that would do that. here is one of them :

[Quick Add Reference Extension for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/10/13/quick-add-reference-extension-for-visual-studio-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: UI]

There is a built-in option for this feature after Visual Studio 2019 version 16.1.

Turn this option on in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Intellisense.

Sorry for the Chinese UI.